# how to call last orders by order id from order table in database

Tags: php, mysql

Dear I need some help according to query from a table (database): such as I have a table "order_detail"
there are some fileds

```
order_id    product_id    product_name    product_price    product_quantity
3           4  
3           5
4
5
6
```

Now I want to show data in thank-you page with all info of order_id 3 . How can I do that from model and controller ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In layman terms:

```
(
    SELECT salary
    FROM tblName
    ORDER BY salary DESC
    LIMIT 1
    OFFSET 1
)
UNION
(
    SELECT salary
    FROM tblName
    ORDER BY salary ASC
    LIMIT 1
    OFFSET 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

For second max:
    `SELECT * FROM salary s ORDER BY s.value DESC LIMIT 1, 1`
For second min:
    `SELECT * FROM salary s ORDER BY s.value ASC LIMIT 1, 1`

Answer (score 1):

For 2nd Maximum

```
SELECT salary_worth
FROM salary
WHERE salary_worth= (SELECT MAX(salary_worth) FROM salary WHERE salary_worth< (SELECT     MAX(salary_worth) FROM salary))
```

For 2nd minimum

```
    SELECT salary_worth
    FROM salary
    WHERE salary_worth= (SELECT MIN(salary_worth) FROM salary WHERE salary_worth> (SELECT     MIN(salary_worth) FROM salary))
```

Answer (score 0):

i know, that this is past question, but i came for next query to solve a problem:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT @w:=@w+1 AS der,salary_worth
        FROM salary, (SELECT @w:=0) AS del ORDER BY salary_worth) del2
   WHERE der IN (2,@w-1);
```